# Is there a way to loop through a list from a specific index that wraps back to the front onwards?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Is there a way to loop through a list from a specific index that wraps back to the front?

Let's imagine a list

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Is there a way to loop from 4 onwards, wrapping back to the front and continuing from there?

Ideally iterating through the original list as I need to modify the values.

Expected output:

```
4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
```

[Visualized example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTOwy.png)

Comment: You can use two for-loops or a while-loop with index increment and additional check or you can create a new list joined together from two slices of the old list and iterate over it or you can use "itertools" module, e. g. functions "cycle" and "islice" together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the iterator directly, then you can use

```
for x in arr[4:] + arr[:4]:
    # operations on x
```

I used the `+` for concatenation assuming it is a native Python `List`

Otherwise if you use indices:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    x = arr[(4 + i)%len(arr)]
    # operations on x
```

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through the original list without creating new ones? I need to be able to modify the values

Comment: Yes sure, you can do your operations in a for loop, I updated the post @Alan

Answer (score 1):

There is. You can slice the list in two and iterate over them in the same loop like this:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
idx = 4
for i in arr[idx:] + arr[:idx]:
    print(i)
```